# Pass unevaluated Mule expression to custom connector

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am writing a Mule custom component using DevKit.  I am writing a connector that will update specific fields and I want the users to be able to specify the fields that will be updated.  I was planning to let them specify the fields using MEL expressions.

So let's say I have defined my processor as follows:

```
@Processor
public void updateFields(String muleExpression)
```

I would like Mule to pass me the expression so I can evaluate it myself to get, process, and then set the value back to the specified field addressed by the expression.  But Mule is processing the expression before passing the String to the processor and I am getting the value of the target field instead of an expression that refers to the target field.

Is there an annotation I can apply to the field or some other way that I can cause Mule to not evaluate the expression and instead pass the expression to me exactly as the user entered it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to this.  There is an `@Literal` annotation.

http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-devkit/3.8.0/apidocs/org/mule/api/annotations/param/package-summary.html

This causes Mule to pass the exact value from the config file to the processor method without any pre-processing.